# Should I delete the b2Body instances created with b2World::CreateBody()?

Tags: box2d

I'm using `b2World::CreateBody()` to create some `b2Body` instances. Should I explicitly `delete` them when deleting the `b2World` instance, or does this happen automatically when the `b2World` instance is destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to.

```
/// Destruct the world. All physics entities are destroyed and all heap memory is released.
    ~b2World();
```